# "Reduced compatibility" from runnable JAR file (2 problems: opacity and JSlider)

Tags: java, jar, opacity, jslider

I have a poker game project, and there are two problems when packed into a runnable JAR-File.

Problem 1:
On the interface of the basic GUI there is a JSlider. Normally, I can click on the bar left or right the slider button to move the slider.

When I start the game from eclipse, it works fine, but as soon I run the program from the jar-file, this action doesn't do anything.

Problem 2:
From time to time, an achievement is unlocked and displayed on the screen. This image of the achievement lays on a JFrame with Color (x,x,x,0), so it should be translucent. Also here, running it from Eclipse shows no problems, while when running it from the JAR file the background is black.

My question now is: How does this are caused? Has this anything to do with JDK/JRE-Version? Or are there other influences?
On my other (and older) notebook with the exact the same Java-version and on my friends Apple Notebook, everything functions fine, also with the jar file.

cmd says: 
java -version
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 221-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Do you have other JREs installed? Try starting your application from command line (javaw -jar "jarname"). If that solves it it may be caused be OS using old JRE to open jars instead of newest installed.

Comment: starting it from cmd works perfectly! thanks! now the question is:
in the folder "Java" i got "jdk1.7.0_03" and "jre7"...further, in the folder of the jdk is already a folder "jre". Under windows system control in programs it shows "Java 6 Update 31", "Java 7 Update 3" and "Java SE Development Kit 7"... How do I proceed for uninstalling the redundant JRE?

Comment: You don't have to. Just right click on jar -> open with.. -> choose default program -> and pick "javaw.exe" in JRE 7 (or JDK 1.7) folder. This should be enough.

Comment: sorry to disturb you again. I tested exactly what you recommended. The problem still extists. Now I uninstalled the JRE 6, and I had to choose a program to open the jar-file by default. I choose again the javaw.exe from the JRE 7, but now the file doesn't open at all. Are there other steps to consider?

Comment: What JRE do you have configured in Eclipse in general/project wise?

Comment: in general it is the 1.7, in this particular project 1.6